# standard deviation as function of probability and mean value

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, probability-density

I would like to build a graph which depicts the relation between the mean (mu) and standard deviation (std) as well as keeping always the same value (e.g., 1.75 in this case) for the 95% probability, under the assumption of a normal distribution. It seems to me that the std is a function of P95% and mu. Am I correct? Any hint is welcome. Thx.

```
for example (mu=mean, std=standard deviation):
1) mu=0, std=? => 95% probability error equals 1.75  
2) mu=0.1, std=? => 95% probability error equals 1.75  
n) mu=1.75, std=0 => 95% probability error equals 1.75
```

**Update:**
It turns out that scipy.stats.norm function
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html

allows to compute the probability density function **norm.pdf(x, loc, scale)** with loc=mean, scale=std

Now, if my understanding is correct, we know: **x** (1.75), **loc** (0 to 1.75), and **norm.pdf** = 0.95. The question how do I get **scale**?

Comment: This is not question suitable for SO. There may be some other sister site http://stackexchange.com/sites# where such question would be on-topic.

Comment: I see. Thank you. you may delete the post then